# Pacifist Palestinian or western pro-Palestinian organizations

Tags: israel, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, pacifism

Are there any pacifist Palestinian or western pro-Palestinian organizations?

I am specifically ask about Palestinian organizations, since, of course there are pacifist on the Israeli side - notably [*B'Tselem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%27Tselem) or [*Breaking the Silence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_the_Silence_(organization)). Understandably, it is easier to be pro-peace when you are on the dominant side of the conflict, but it is hard to believe that all the Palestinians support Islamist ideology promoted by groups like Hamas.

Please support the answers by the statements of these organizations regarding the current conflict in Gaza (especially their statements in response to October 7.)

Related: [*What is the pacifist position on Ukraine?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74211/what-is-the-pacifist-position-on-ukraine)

**Remarks:**
As correctly pointed in the comments, B'Tselem and Breaking the Silence are, strictly speaking, not pacifist - but rather Israeli organizations condemning the violence by the Israeli side. I am interested, whether there are also Palestinian or pro-Palestinian organizations opposing Palestinian violence, or promoting peaceful resistance (like Ghandi or Mandela in later years.)

Comment: Do you mean 'pro-Western Palestian' instead of 'Western pro-Palestinian'?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking about because pro-peace is not the same thing as pacifist which is not the same thing as non-violent. Neither B'Tselem nor Breaking the Silence are pacifist groups.

Comment: @StandwithGaza those who do not believe in the solution of the conflict via violence. Otherwise, Hamas is also pro-peace, but on its own terms and after killing anyone who opposes their vision. If you have a more nuanced view on the Israeli organizations, include it in your answer (quoting the relevant information.)

Comment: I recently saw an interview with two fathers, an Israeli who had lost a son in a Palestinian terror attack and a Palestinian who had lost a son in an IDF military action, who had founded an organization promoting a peaceful coexistence of Israelis and Palestinians. Unfortunately, I can't remember the name of the organization. Also the interview did not go into detail about the program of this organization, e.g. whether they are arguing for a two-state or one-state solution.

Answer (score 7):

There are several pacifist organizations that are joint Israeli-Palestinian:

- [EcoPeace](https://ecopeaceme.org): "a unique organization that brings together Jordanian, Palestinian and Israeli environmentalists. Our primary objective is the promotion of cooperative efforts to protect our shared environmental heritage. In so doing, we seek to advance both sustainable regional development and the creation of necessary conditions for lasting peace in our region. EcoPeace has offices in Amman, Ramallah, and Tel-Aviv."
- [The Parents Circle](https://www.theparentscircle.org/en/about_eng-2/): "The Parents Circle – Families Forum (PCFF) is a joint Israeli-Palestinian organization of over 600 families, all of whom have lost an immediate family member to the ongoing conflict. Moreover, the PCFF has concluded that the process of reconciliation between nations is a prerequisite to achieving a sustainable peace. The organization thus utilizes all resources available in education, public meetings and the media, to spread these ideas"

Comment: Both examples are joint Israeli-Palestinian organizations. Are there any solely Palestinian peace promoting organizations?